How is a Lamport signature implemented in real world scenarios?
I understand the Lamport signature scheme (and its variations) in general, but how is it used?

If I want to sign some documents, where do I publish my Lamport public keys?
How does someone know where to go to get my public keys?
How do I signify that a public keyset has been utilized to sign a document already?
How do I revoke the unused portion of a public keyset?

And the same sort of questions related to signing messages in real-time internet transactions.
Is there any sort of standard; or is everything application dependent and everyone just rolls their own each time?

Well, one time signatures (such as Lamport) really aren't used that much in practice, hence there really isn't a 'standard'.
One way that I have heard one-way signatures be used is to authenticate a series of messages (travelling over a reliable transport).  Each message would include:

The next Lamport public key
The actual text being transported
The signature of the above two (signed with the public key included in the previous message)

This works (as long as you have some way of establishing an initial public key, and as long as the transport is reliable).
On the other hand, I have only heard it proposed - I haven't heard of anyone actually using this.
You appear to be thinking of 'we'll bundle a number of Lamport public keys together, and then use each one to sign a different message'.  In that case, using a standard stateful hash-based signature algorithm (such as LMS or XMSS) makes more sense.  These encode a number of one-time signatures (Winternitz rather than Lamport), and then use a Merkle tree to tie them together - the public key is essentially the root of the Merkle tree (that is, short), and placing the Merkle tree authentication path into the signature doesn't add that much length (compared to the Winternitz siganture we need to add anyways).
